# extract values from map interface

Tags: go

below is my code

```
func main() {
    var a interface{}
    b := make(map[string]interface{})
    b["mac_addr"] = "fa:16:3e:ba:95:bd"
    b["type"] = "fixed"
    b["addr"] = "1.1.1.1"
    a = b
    fmt.Println(a)
}
```

a gives me output
`map[addr:1.1.1.1 mac_addr:fa:16:3e:ba:95:bd type:fixed]`

issue is how do I access value of addr from a

Comment: `a.(map[string]interface{})["addr"]`

Comment: thanks, yes it did work, i was able to do get the required value. But I am getting another type, below is the structure, how do I get the value from this, I am getting 

```Addresses: (map[string]interface {}) (len=1) {
  (string) (len=7) "network": ([]interface {}) (len=1 cap=1) {
   (map[string]interface {}) (len=2) {
    (string) (len=15) "type": (string) (len=5) "fixed",
    (string) (len=4) "addr": (string) (len=7) "1.1.1.1"
   }
  }
 }```

Comment: managed to get this working. here is the working solution.
```
 for _, y := range Addresses {
  for _, z := range y.(interface{}).([]interface{}) {
   log.Println(z.(map[string]interface{})["addr"].(string))
  }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

use assert

`val,ok:=a.(map[string]interface{})`

`if ok {`

```
fmt.println(val["addr"])
```

`}`

Comment: thanks, it works. Also how do I deal with

```[map[addr:1.1.1.1 mac_addr:fa:16:3e:ba:95:bd type:fixed]]```